# Mod_rewrite, how to stop rule applying to one query string?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a list of rewrite rules, but one of the rules is applying to something I need it to not apply to.

Here is the rewrite rule causing the problem,

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /category.php?category=$1 [L]

It's meant to rewrite .com/catname/ to /category.php?category=catname which it does fine, but I need it to not apply to anything beginning with /feed/, as these aren't handled by category.php.
I have this rule for the feeds, but it's not getting a chance to do it's thing...

RewriteRule ^feed/([^/]*)/$ /feed/?cat=$1 [L]

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the sequence of your rules? You should put the `/feed/` rule as first one.

Comment: Hi, I've got the following. Ive tried with the feed one first, but it doesn't work :(



RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^feed/([^/]*)/$ /feed/?cat=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^download-([^/]*)/$ /software.php?shortname=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/screenshots/$ /screenshots.php?screenshots=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/screenshots/([^/]*)/$ /screenshots.php?screenshots=$1&shot=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /category.php?category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^download/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /send.php?key=$1&s=$2 [L]

Answer (score 1):

Put the rule for the feeds before the other rule.